# how to pass pointer to constructor in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

have a derived class that needs to take a pointer as a constructor for the base class.

how do you do this in c++, i tried it but it gave me a bug.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
protected:
    int *num;
public:
    Base(int *num);
    virtual void print();
};

Base::Base(int *num){
    this->num = num;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int *num) : Base(*num);
    void print();
};

Derived::print(){
    cout << "int value : " << *(this->num);
};

int main(){
    int num = 5;
    int *p = &num;
    
    Derived derived(p);
    derived.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Derived(int *num) : Base(num) {}`

Comment: What does "it gave me a bug" mean?

Comment: `*num` is not a pointer. Its an integer.

Comment: Why do you think that "it gave you a bug"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **constructor initializer list** of `Derived` you have to write `Base(num)` instead of `Base(*num)` as shown below:

```
Derived(int *num): Base(num) 
{
   //code here
}
```

Note that you don't have to **dereference** the pointer `num` which you were doing while using it in the constructor initializer list. When you dereference `num`, you got an `int`. And so you were passing that `int` to the `Base` constructor.